# Prove limit of a sequence.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Just working through some practice problems before my final in a couple of weeks and I ran into one I couldn't figure out.  Thanks!

Part A:

Let $ a_n = \gamma^{s/n} $ for some $ \gamma >1 $, some $ s>0$, and all positive integeers n.  Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 1 $

Part B:

Fix some $s>0$. Determine (with proof!)

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} {\gamma^{s/n}-1\over\gamma^{1/n}-1} $$

Comment: When you say $\lim_{x \to \infty} a_n = 1$, do you mean $n$ instead of $x$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint A:** Note that $\log(a_n)=\frac sn\log(\gamma)$

**Hint B:** Let $x=\gamma^{1/n}$ and consider $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^s-1}{x-1}$